# PHP: How do I display a Yes/No output if current date=list of dates provided in?

Tags: php, html, datetime, if-statement

I think an if, else statement would be the way to go, but I'm not sure exactly. My PHP knowledge is limited to tweaking wordpress files. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

P.S: This question is not regarding wordpress, but php in general

Comment: Why have you tagged laravel?

Comment: Some code with an example of what your trying to achieve would make your requirement clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right way.You have to check **IF** current date is **IN ARRAY** of dates.
To help you,i provide the
[PHP in_array documentation link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

I hope this help.

**[EDIT]**

A short example, if you want to output **OK** if a **fruit** is in the **fruit list**.

```
<?php
   $fruit = 'bannana'; // This corresponds to your current date
   $fruitList = ['apple','orange','bannana']; //this corresponds to your date list

   //IF $fruit is in the array $fruitList
   if (in_array($fruit, $fruitList)) {
     echo 'OK';
   } else {
     echo 'NOT OK';
   }
```

Comment: Whilst links to information are useful, it would be better if you included a basic example of what you are proposing as a solution in your answer.  (Please also if you provide links to the manual - normally they would be to the English version)

Comment: This helps a lot @AlexandrePainchaud. Also, if I may trouble you some more, how do I call the current date? would date() work?

Comment: @SumitShetty It depends on your needs. In the list if you store date formatted like YYYY-mm-dd you can use date('Y-m-d') but you can also use DateTime Object with format method.
Check date function on php documentation for more informations about date format.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've found thanks to @Alexandre

```
<?php
$date = date('d-m-Y');; // This corresponds to your current date
$dateList = ['23-07-2018','26-01-2018','27-01-2018','10-02-2018','14-02-2018','24-02-2018','02-03-2018','10-03-2018','24-03-2018','30-03-2018']; //this corresponds to your date list

//IF $date is in the array $dateList
if (in_array($date, $dateList)) {
    echo 'No';
} else {
    echo 'Yes';

} 
?>
```

Hope this helps anyone who's looking for something similar.